# React AJAX post request does not go to success/error method

Tags: ajax, reactjs, post

I have a React Component which calls an AJAX POST request. 
The POST request creates an entry in the database as expected. (status 201 returned) However the success/error methods of the same are not called.

```
$.ajax({
            url: '/api/put/comment/',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            data: comment,
            beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                console.log('before send');
                xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken', getCookie('csrftoken'));
            },
            success: function(data) {
                console.log('success');
                this.loadData();
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, err) {
                console.log('error');
                this.setState({data:comments});
                console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
            }
        });
```

The request is called through a button click. Also the browser hangs once the request is made, and the solution is to open a new tab.

Also i do not see the POST request on the Network tab of Chrome, but see it on the backend. 
Any hints?

Comment: ES6 **arrow functions** should work.

Comment: Where are you using ajax request? in some handler? Also you should try `fetch` or `axios` as they are promise based will be really helpful.

Comment: a form onSubmit calls a function which contains the AJAX call.. 

cool.. will try axios or fetch.. and post the results here..

Comment: worked using axios. not sure what the AJAX call issue is though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using ES6 arrow functions or bind your functions with `this`

```
$.ajax({
            url: '/api/put/comment/',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            data: comment,
            beforeSend:(xhr) => {
                console.log('before send');
                xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken', getCookie('csrftoken'));
            },
            success:(data) => {
                console.log('success');
                this.loadData();
            },
            error:(xhr, status, err) => {
                console.log('error');
                this.setState({data:comments});
                console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
            }
        });
```

Comment: no luck even with the arrow functions or with bind(this)

Comment: no.. 
the beforeSend function gets called.. on the server i see 201 for the request.. and then thats it.. nothing else happens..